# C pointer segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, space

I have this C code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

char *buf;
int c,s; int port=45678;

int recv_m(int c,char *buf);

void get(){

char fileNameBuf[20];
int i=0;
char *s = buf;

if (*s=='/') {
    s++;
    while (*s!=' ') {

        fileNameBuf[i]=*s;
        *s++; 
        i++;
    }
        fileNameBuf[i]='\0';    

}
}

int main(){

//server connected
while ((c = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &client, (socklen_t *) &clientlen)) > 0){
    // Do whatever a web server does.

    char recv_buf[50];
    char *r=recv_buf;
    while(recv(c, r , 1, 0)!=0){
         //stores the received message in recv_buf
    }


    recv_buf[i]='\0';

          if (strncmp(recv_buf, "GET ", 4)==0){
                            buf=recv_buf+4;
            get();
          }

}
    return (0);
}
```

*buf points to string `/index.html HTTP/1.0`.  At the end of the function, fileNameBuf should store the string `index.html`.

The number of times in the while loop should be 10.  When I run this code, i = 381 and I get a segmentation fault (core dump).

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the whole code, so *buf is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your assumptions about what is in `buf` must be faulty — or we're faulty in our interpretation of what you mean when you say:

> `*buf` points to string `"/index.html HTTP/1.1"`.

If you declared `char **buf;` and set:

```
char *str = "/index.html HTTP/1.1";
char **buf = str;
```

Then `*buf` points to the start of the string.  This is why creating an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) is important; it removes the ambiguities.

---

#### An SSCCE

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *buf = "/index.html HTTP/1.1";

static
void get(void)
{
    char fileNameBuf[10];
    int i=0;

    if (*buf=='/')
    { 
        buf++;
        while (*buf!=' ')
        {
            fileNameBuf[i]=*buf;
            buf++; 
            i++;
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    printf("%.*s\n", (int)sizeof(fileNameBuf), fileNameBuf);
}

int main(void)
{
    get();
    return 0;
}
```

produces this output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
index.html
```

Granted, I had to take care not to print beyond the end of the array.  Your array is minimally sized; it cannot hold a string containing the file name (no space for the null terminator).  But it should not crash — if `char *buf = "/index.html HTTP/1.1";`!

---

#### Completed code — stage 1

This is closely based on what was submitted as the program.  It compiles cleanly — I've not tried running it.

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

char *buf;
int c, s; int port = 45678;
struct sockaddr_in server, client;
char *ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
int clientlen = sizeof(client);
int portset = 0;

int recv_m(int c, char *buf);

static
void get(void)
{
    printf("in get method\n");
    char fileNameBuf[20];
    int i = 0;
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    char *s = buf;

    if (*s == '/')
    {
        printf("buf==/\n");
        s++;
        while (*s != ' ')
        {
            // printf("%c\n",*buf);
            // printf("in while\n");
            fileNameBuf[i] = *s;
            s++;
            i++;
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
        fileNameBuf[i]='\0';
        printf("<<%s>>\n", fileNameBuf);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("!= '/'\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    bzero(&server, sizeof(server));

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);

// if (!inet_aton(ipaddress, &server.sin_addr))
//  fprintf (stderr, "inet_addr() conversion error\n");

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Create socket
    if (!s) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("binded\n");
    if (listen(s, SOMAXCONN) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Waiting for connection\n");
    while ((c = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &client, (socklen_t *) &clientlen)) > 0)
    {
        // Do whatever a web server does.
        printf("got connected\n");
        char recv_buf[50];
        char el[4] = "\r\n\r\n";
        int h = 0; int i = 0;
        char *r = recv_buf;
        while (recv(c, r, 1, 0) != 0)
        {

            if (h == 4) break;

            if (*r == el[h]) {
                h++;
            }
            r++;
            i++;

            if (h == 4) break;
        }

        recv_buf[i] = '\0';

        printf("%s\n", recv_buf);


        if (  strncmp(recv_buf, "GET ", 4) == 0) {
            printf("check get\n");
            buf = recv_buf+4;
            printf("%s\n", buf);
            get();
        }

    }
    return(0);

}
```

This is not an SSCCE.  All the code related to setting up the socket and reading from the socket should be tangential to the problem at hand.

#### Reduced Code — Stage 2

The reduction process involves eliminating the inessential.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *buf;

static void get(void)
{
    printf("in get method\n");
    char fileNameBuf[20];
    int i = 0;
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    char *s = buf;

    if (*s == '/')
    {
        printf("buf==/\n");
        s++;
        while (*s != ' ')
        {
            fileNameBuf[i] = *s;
            s++;
            i++;
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
        fileNameBuf[i]='\0';
        printf("<<%s>>\n", fileNameBuf);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("!= '/'\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char recv_buf[50];
    strcpy(recv_buf, "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");

    printf("<<%s>>\n", recv_buf);

    if (strncmp(recv_buf, "GET ", 4) == 0)
    {
        printf("check get\n");
        buf = recv_buf+4;
        printf("%s\n", buf);
        get();
    }
    return(0);
}
```

This too compiles cleanly; unfortunately, it also runs successfully for me (GCC 4.8.1, Mac OS X 10.8.4):

```
<<GET /index.html HTTP/1.1

>>
check get
/index.html HTTP/1.1


in get method
/index.html HTTP/1.1


buf==/
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
<<index.html>>
```

This happens sometimes; you are too ruthless in your clean-up.  So, you have to go back to the previous code and remove things more slowly.

#### Retrenching — Stage 3

Let's take the full code from Stage 1 and run it locally.  The browser can connect to `localhost:45678/index.html` and the output is:

```
binded
Waiting for connection
got connected
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:45678

check get
/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:45678

in get method
/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:45678

buf==/
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
<<index.html>>
```

There is nothing sent back to the waiting browser (it's still waiting, but will time out shortly).  The code loops back to the next accept; it isn't clear that it shuts up shop properly, but it didn't crash on the first cycle.

So, this has been a somewhat fruitless exercise...your code seems to work OK.  It should still be improved — starting off by making every one of those global variables into a local in `main()`, and then passing `buf` to a modified `get()` with the signature `void get(char *buf)`.

Does the code you showed really crash for you?  If so, what does the debugger say about why it crashes?

---

#### Bullet-proofing — Stage 4

After establishing that the string pointed to by `buf` was actually `"/index.html\r\n\r\n" and not`"/index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"`, it is clear that I was remiss in not ensuring that the code would not read past the end of null terminated strings nor write past the ends of buffers.  However, this is precisely why an SSCCE is so important, and why diagnostic printing is so important.  If the question had included the actual string that was being scanned, it would have been a lot simpler to spot the issue.

This code is more nearly bullet-proof.  Amongst other major changes, it attempts to read the request in a single `recv()` operation, rather than reading the request byte by byte.  This puts the onus on avoiding an overflow on `recv()`.  All the global variables are gone; `buf` is passed to `get()` as an argument.  `get()` has been written to detect EOS and overlong names, as well as handling names up to the first space. It still has the debug code for each character in the file name. The code in `main()` has been dolled up to send back a response that is valid HTTP — or valid enough HTTP — with a bit of HTML that changes each time it is handled.  It's interesting seeing the requests the browser makes.  There's also an error reporting function that writes to standard error, takes a format string and arguments as with `printf()` et al, and also adds the correct error number and message for the system error, and then exits with a failure status.  This makes error reporting less painful; a one-line call suffices for each error, instead of 3 or 4 lines (depending on your choice of formatting).  The errors can be more expressive than `perror()` too.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...);

static
void get(char *buf)
{
    printf("in get method\n");
    char fileNameBuf[256];
    size_t i = 0;
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    char *s = buf;

    if (*s == '/')
    {
        printf("buf==/\n");
        s++;
        while (*s != '\0' && *s != ' ' && i < sizeof(fileNameBuf))
        {
            printf("i = %3d: c = %3d = 0x%.2X = '%c'\n",
                   (int)i, *s, *s & 0xFF, isprint(*s) ? *s : '.');
            fileNameBuf[i++] = *s++;
        }
        fileNameBuf[i]='\0';
        printf("<<%s>>\n", fileNameBuf);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("!= '/'\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *buf;
    int fd;
    int s;
    int port = 45678;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int clientlen = sizeof(client);
    int msgnum = 314159;

    bzero(&server, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (!s)
        err_exit("socket()\n");
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
        err_exit("bind()\n");
    printf("bound to address\n");
    if (listen(s, SOMAXCONN) < 0)
        err_exit("listen()\n");
    printf("Waiting for connection\n");

    while ((fd = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &client, (socklen_t *) &clientlen)) > 0)
    {
        printf("got connection\n");
        char recv_buf[4096];
        char el[5] = "\r\n\r\n";
        ssize_t length;
        /* Read message in one go; leave space for a null at the end */
        if ((length = recv(fd, recv_buf, sizeof(recv_buf)-1, 0)) > 0)
        {
            recv_buf[length] = '\0';
            if (strstr(recv_buf, el) == 0)
                err_exit("Incomplete message (%d bytes and no CRLF, CRLF pair)\n", length);
            printf("%d: <<%s>>\n", (int)length, recv_buf);

            if (strncmp(recv_buf, "GET ", 4) == 0)
            {
                printf("check get\n");
                buf = recv_buf + 4;
                printf("<<%s>>\n", buf);
                get(buf);
                char message[256];
                char format1[] =
                    "<html><head><title>Hello World!</title></head>"
                    "<body><h1>This is no fun at all (%d).</h1></body></html>\r\n\r\n";
                int msg_len = snprintf(message, sizeof(message), format1, msgnum++);
                char format2[] =
                    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                    "Content-Length: %d\r\n"
                    "Content-Encoding: UTF-8\r\n\r\n%s";
                char response[1024];
                size_t nbytes = snprintf(response, sizeof(response), format2,
                                         msg_len, message);
                write(fd, response, nbytes);
            }
        }
        close(fd);
    }
    return(0);
}

static void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: but buf is a pointer that points to string recv_buf, or did do it wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that buf is a char array. If so, you should access the buf using a char pointer. Try this:

```
int main ()  {

    char buf[] = "/index.html HTTP/1.0";
    char fileNameBuf[10];
    int i=0;

    char *s = buf;
    if (*s=='/') {

        s++;
        while (*s!=' ') {
            fileNameBuf[i]=*s;
            *s++;
            i++;
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
}
```

If buf is an array of char and even though arrays and pointers have several things in common, doing buf++ is not legal by C.Here is a text from Kernighan/Ritchie C book. You have probably buf declared as an array as well.

> There is one difference between an array name and a pointer that must be kept in mind. A pointer is a variable, so pa=a and pa++ are legal. But an array name is not a variable; constructions like a=pa and a++ are illegal.

Due to this reason, doing "arr++" would be an error in the following code.

```
int main() {
    int arr[10];
    int *ptr = arr;

    arr++; // Would be illegal.
    ptr++; // This is okay.
}
```

Comment: @user1887339 Your recv() call looks suspicious. I have updated (edited) my answer.You need to pass length greater than 1 in the recv() call.

Comment: i use 1 bcuz i'm receiving the message character one by one until "\r\n\r\n" shows up.

Comment: Thnx.. I will edit it.. But, you probably should read the whole thing in one shot. recv() is a system call and so is pretty expensive.

Comment: @user1887339 In that case, how do you much data (bytes) you have received. What if we received more than 20 bytes? The rcv_buf would be able to handle more than 20 bytes, but get() function would not. So, if we pass more than 20, then fileNameBuf would go beyond 20 and crash. So, you should ensure than the buf read from is not more than 20 bytes. One way is to check the returned value of recv() when we pass a large enough buffer so that we can read it in one shot.

Comment: One last note. As we know that recv() function returns 0 only when the  peer TCP closes the connection. The while() loop would continue to read till the recv() returns 0. In that case, if the webserver returns a lot of content in one page, then you are likely reading way more than 20 (or even 50) bytes!